# Link a word graph with a word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

i'm trying to visualize my data that i have stored in a word table. I can call the table data with `ThisDocument.Tables(6).Cell(i,j).Range.Text`. I tried to copy this data to the datasheet of the word graph, but this was unsuccessful.

[Word table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGu4s.jpg)

The chart has to visualize the amount of currency in a timeline with time on the x-axis and the amount of money on the y-axis. I have allready inserted a chart in my word document but i need to access its datasheet.

[Graph in word that i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2VQx.jpg)

Does anyone have an example code that i can use to solve this problem?

I'm trying to build my code like this:

```
Dim graph As Word.Chart
Set graph = ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).Chart
If Not Len(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text) = 2 Then
    Dim temp As String
    For i = 0 To ThisDocument.Tables(3).Rows.Count - 2
        graph.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Left(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 3).Range.Text, Len(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 3).Range.Text) - 2)
        temp = Left(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 4).Range.Text, Len(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 4).Range.Text) - 2)
        graph.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1 + i, 2).Value = Right(temp, Len(temp) - 2)
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: "I tried to copy this data to the datasheet of the word graph, but this was unsuccessful" How did you try to copy the data to the datasheet, do you have some VBA code that's not working which you can share with us?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to build my code like this:

```
Dim graph As Word.Chart

Set graph = ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).Chart

If Not Len(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text) = 2 Then
    Dim temp As String
    For i = 0 To ThisDocument.Tables(3).Rows.Count - 2
        graph.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Left(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 3).Range.Text, Len(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 3).Range.Text) - 2)
        temp = Left(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 4).Range.Text, Len(ThisDocument.Tables(3).Cell(2 + i, 4).Range.Text) - 2)
        graph.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1 + i, 2).Value = Right(temp, Len(temp) - 2)
    Next i
End If
```